# cloning a database with few entries

Tags: mysql, tableau-api

Is there a way to clone a database containing millions of entries with very few entries say `1000`.

I am creating a analysis which doesn't need to access huge data. For this I am trying to setup a small database which has the same properties as the original db but with very few entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table small like large;    
insert into table small select * from large limit 1000;
```

You'll have to do this for each table in the database but you should be able to script it fairly easily using queries from the command line

Comment: this way u have to do that for each table. But my database has like 500 tables and this isn't the best way

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to create a Tableau data extract, and specify the percentage of rows from the originial data source to keep in your extract. You can also apply other filters.

Then you can develop your visualizations by working quickly and locally on a small subset of the data via the extract. And then switch back to the original data source when you're ready to see how the visualization behaves when fed all the data.

Extracts are associated with the data connection. The exact location of the menu items depends on the version of Tableau, but look under either the Data menu, or right click on a data connection to find the extract related commands.